How to handle unexpected errors thrown within the root layout in a Next 14 application?
I want to handle unexpected errors in my Next 14 application.
My goal is to have a global error fallback UI that will handle all errors thrown within my root layout.
Based on the documentation, I could create a global error file inside my app directory which is responsible for handling all unexpected errors.
My project directory looks like the following:

While my global error page component:

For testing purposes, I threw an error inside my About page.

I expected the global error page component to get executed and replace the root layout. Instead, I got the following: 

Am I doing something wrong?

As per the NextJS documentation:

Good to know:
global-error.js is only enabled in production. In development, our
error overlay will show instead.

